# MAILCHIMP ERROR CORREOS

Tags: html, email

Estoy usando mailchimp para el envio de un mailing, nos dieron una lista de 500 correos y al momento de importar esos correos todo bien pero cuando voy a enviar el mailing me arroja el siguiente error y le doy resolver me borra la mayoria de los correos, estuve buscando informacion y dice que el sistema de mailchimp reconoce muchos correos como spam, nunca antes habia pasado.

Que se puede hacer en estos casos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes indicar en el apartado **To:** un solo buzón de correo al que le enviaras la información, no puedes ni debes poner todos los correos separados por coma dentro de **To:** porque mailchimp te lo detecta como abuso.